# How to add data to an array attribute in MongoDB using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, mean

I just want to add to the articles attribute the title of different articles.
My `user.controller.js` file has this function

```
module.exports.savearticle = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    req._id,
    {
      $addToSet: { articles: req.body.articles }
    },
    {
      new: true
    },
    function(err, savedArticle) {
      if (err) {
        res.send("Error saving article");
      } else {
        res.json(savedArticle);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

I have a separate router page, `index.router.js`, with all my routers, which includes the route for this function

```
router.post("/savearticle", ctrlUser.savearticle);
```

Im using Postman to test the function.
In the form-data im setting a key to `articles` and the value to `article1`.
My response is this

```
{
    "articles": [
        null
    ]
}
```

Why is it coming out null?
I had done `console.log(req.body.articles)` and it returns `undefined`.
Why is it `undefined`?
Shouldn't it say `article1`?

This is the schema I'm making in my `user.model.js` page

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    required: "Full name can't be empty"
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: "E-mail can't be empty",
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: "Password can't be empty",
    minlength: [4, "Password must be atleast 6 characters"]
  },
  saltSecret: String,
  articles: Array
});
```

And this is the user registration function in the `user.controller.js` file

```
module.exports.register = (req, res, next) => {
  var user = new User();
  user.fullName = req.body.fullName;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.password = req.body.password;
  user.articles = [];
  user.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(doc);
    } else {
      if (err.code == 11000) {
        res.status(422).send(["Duplicate email address found."]);
      } else return next(err);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: How could we know? You're not showing us the JSON body you're passing to your API. This doesn't really have anything to do with Mongo as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay I added the schema that I'm sending and the user registration. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. What is `req.body.articles`? What is the value of `req.body.articles` and `req.body` at the point where you use it in your mongo query? I'd bet that it's not what you expect.

Comment: oh. yeah i'm extremely new to this and following along with a tutorial so i'm not 100% sure what `req.body.articles` is. i thought that in postman, the key value pair would set `req.body.articles` to `article1` which would in turn add `article1` to the database

Comment: I think you need to post a JSON body something like `{"articles": {"a":1,"b":2}}` (which makes "articles" as opposed to "article" an odd name.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `findOneAndUpdate` with invalid parameters. First check req._id type (by breakpoint on debug or console.log(req._id)), if it's `string`, you should convert it to `mongoose.mongo.ObjectId`.

```
module.exports.savearticle = (req, res, next) => {
  let userId = req._id;
  if((typeof userId) === 'string'){
     userId = mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(userId);
  }
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id : userId},
    {
      $push: {articles: {$each : req.body.articles } } //$each need if  req.body.articles is an array, else use  $push: {articles: req.body.articles } instead of
    },
    {new: true},
    function(err, savedArticle) {
      if (err) {
        res.send("Error saving article");
      } else {
        res.json(savedArticle);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do following:

1. parse your req._id into Object Id

`req._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req._id);`

2. In Postman, send data in body as row type and select JSON from dropdown.
   [image: See PostMan]

**Note**: If you want only unique value in array "articles", use `#addToSet` otherwise use `$push`.